# How to detect CRC errs in an file when extracting from a zip

Tags: c#, .net, zip, extract, crc

I work for a company that has a cloud base application that allows users to transfer data files from the PC to their mobile device and back again allowing the users to update and edited their files out in the field.

Randomly I will run across an issue where during the transfer of the file through the interwebs, the zip structure gets damaged and a random file in the zip will have crc errors.

Typically it will be an image, but not always. This causes issues with our software and prevents the files from loading. I wrote a tool that scans the zip file and looks for and repairs errors in the xml files in the zip; however, the System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory function is not throwing an errors, it extracts the file and writes it out.

The System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory call I make later then zips up this file, again without error resulting in a zip that still has a crc error and still will not open in our software.

So here is my connumdry, How can I check the files I am extracting from the zip for crc errors and not place them in the new zip once i am done with my other work?

I have tried a few things and short of loading every file type in to a reader of some sort (there are a dozen or so file types that may be in the zip) I got nothing.

P.S. I am very new to C# and have no formal coding training so I may ask some dumb questions, sorry. :D

An example can be found [here](https://alamodeinc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jason_k_alamode_com/EaR4SLO1f6BIjwC8rH3FuaIB-_q4jcehjAnmZTiVgYwSVw?e=g3oFtd)

OK I tried what was suggested and here is what I get

Using the following code:

```
//https://johnlnelson.com/tag/zip-archive-c/ using ZipArchive
string zipFile = FileName;
string extractPath = @"C:\Temp\XAP\" + xapName;
ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFile);

if (zipArchive.Entries != null && zipArchive.Entries.Count > 0)
{
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipArchive.Entries)
{
entry.ExtractToFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName));
}
}
```

and it generates the following error

```
ERROR:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Temp\XAP\CRC in bmp\assignmentmap.bmp'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile
```

The code fails to extract any of the files in the zip not just the corrupted one.

Comment: System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory should throw an InvalidDataException if it encounters an corrupt entry. But since ZIP file entries allow to store several meta data (such as CRC) in different ways, it could be a limitation of the ZipFile class that it does not detect the problematic entry. But i am just guessing here, i am not really sure about ZipFile's behavior. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) For testing purposes, perhaps you could try ZipArchive to read the entries from a corrupted ZIP archive to check (A) if ZipArchive is actually able to get the CRC value from the ZIP entry header, and if it does then (B) whether it will throw an exception when reading the uncompressed data stream from the ZipArchiveEntries. Alternatively, if the test with ZipArchive is fruitless and your project and business requirements/constraints allow usage of 3rd-party libraries, you might use SharpZipLib or similar libraries (license terms permitting, of course).

Comment: (3/2) Small, but perhaps important omission from my 2nd comment: If ZipArchive/ZipArchiveEntry can provide the CRC32 from each ZIP entry header, but reading the uncompressed datastream of a corrupt entry from beginning to end will not throw, you could still calculcate the CRC32 checksum from the data from the uncompressed data stream and compare this with the CRC32 value from the ZIP entry header by yourself (which would avoid a dependency on some 3rd-party library)

Comment: Okay, last comment, i promise! (Perhaps ;) You say that System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory creates a ZIP archive with entries that have CRC errors. That should not happen. Which makes me believe that there is potentially a misunderstanding here. Are you talking about the CRC32 values stored in the ZIP entry meta data (which are part of the ZIP file format), or are you talking about some other CRC values/types that are not related to the ZIP file format itself?

Comment: This is an interesting behaviour. In a standard case, files with incorrect CRC _(corrupted compressed data)_ should not be extracted _(at least not after the point of corruption)_. After creating new zip file, there should be no corrupted file _(except possible incomplete files)_. Since I do not have a real code to test your case, only a theory: Try to test the files with 7zip. When 7zip do not report error, zip files are OK and the problem is elsewhere. Otherwise you probably need to make custom `UnzipToDir` or `TestZip` function that will work with separate files.

Comment: I uploaded a sample file containing the error. If I open the zip in windows I get no error, if I try to extract the bmp, I get an error. Winrar opens the fine just fine, but gives an error:
CRC in bmp.zip: Checksum error in assignmentmap.bmp. The file is corrupt
CRC in bmp.zip: The archive is corrupt

Comment: @JasonKrise, try reading this ZIP file using ZipArchive/ZipArchiveEntry. Does the ZipArchiveEntry for the bmp provide a CRC? If so, try reading the complete uncompressed datastream (from beginning to end) of the ZipArchiveEntry. Is an exception thrown?

Comment: @elgonzo I will try to do what I think you just said. I won't be able to do it today, but I will try. My program experience is limited to what I have found online from others and was able to pick out something I could use. This is my 4th attempt at writing an app in C# ever. So I am beyond a little green, I think I might glow in the dark :D

Comment: Addendum + correction: Out of curiosity i looked at your ZIP and tried ZipArchive + ZipArchiveEntry today. And like ZipFile, it also does not throw when extracting the corrupted file. Also, it seems ZipArchiveEntry only provides a property for the CRC32 if your build target is .NET Core 2.1. That means if your build target is different/older, forget about ZipArchive + ZipArchiveEntry. My apologies for not noticing that detail earlier :(. Thus, unless your build target is .NET Core 2.1, the best option is to use a 3rd-party library for handling the ZIP files...

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks, I am using .net 4.5 due to other requirements.

Comment: @JasonKrise. when you get the `DirectoryNotFoundException` it means you need to create the directory first. Replace: `entry.ExtractToFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName));` with `string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName); Directory.Create(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)); entry.ExtractToFile(fileName);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is a problem in the build in `ZipArchive` from .NET Framework 4.5. Corrupted files are not signalised in any way. And there seems to be another problem in `SharpZipLib`. Full code of example bellow, including the detection of corruption for .NET Framework:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

using DotNetZipFile = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile;

namespace Stackoverflow_unzip_test
{
  internal static class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      Extract45Framework("CRCerror.zip", ".\\Unpack_1");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine();
      ExtractSharpZipLib("CRCerror.zip", ".\\Unpack_2");
    }

    private static void Extract45Framework(string zipFile, string extractPath)
    {
      ZipArchive zipArchive = DotNetZipFile.OpenRead(zipFile);

      if (zipArchive.Entries != null && zipArchive.Entries.Count > 0)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Extracting...");
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipArchive.Entries)
        {
          try
          {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name))
            {
              // skip directory
              continue;
            }

            string file = Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName);
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
              Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" - '" + entry.FullName + "'...");
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
              //Console.WriteLine("   - delete previous version...");
              File.Delete(file);
            }

            entry.ExtractToFile(file);
            long length = (new FileInfo(file)).Length;
            if (entry.Length != length)
            {
              Console.WriteLine($"   - Failed to extract! Extracted only {length} out of {entry.Length} bytes");
            }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("   - Failed to extract: " + ex.Message);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private static void ExtractSharpZipLib(string zipFileName, string extractPath)
    {
      using (var file = File.OpenRead(zipFileName))
      using (ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(file))
      {
        ZipEntry entry;
        try
        {
          while ((entry = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
          {
            SaveFile(zip, entry, extractPath);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("   - Failed to parse zip: " + ex.Message);
        }
      }
    }

    private static void SaveFile(ZipInputStream zip, ZipEntry entry, string extractPath)
    {
      if (entry.IsDirectory)
      {
        return;
      }

      try
      {
        string file = Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.Name);
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" - '" + entry.Name + "'...");
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
          //Console.WriteLine("   - delete previous version...");
          File.Delete(file);
        }

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        long length = 0;
        using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(file))
        {
          int readLength;
          while ((readLength = zip.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) != 0)
          {
            fs.Write(data, 0, readLength);
            length += readLength;
          }
        }

        if (entry.Size != length)
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"   - Failed to extract! Extracted only {length} out of {entry.Size} bytes");
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("   - Failed to extract: " + ex.Message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Application output:

```
Extracting...
 - 'tadd1.tx'...
 - 'assignmentmap.bmp'...
   - Failed to extract! Extracted only 34216 out of 34830 bytes
 - 'sketch.dsk'...


 - 'tadd1.tx'...
 - 'assignmentmap.bmp'...
   - Failed to extract: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   - Failed to parse zip: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: count
```

Comment: Nice, that looks like it could be a lot of help. Your Extract45Framework process would identify any files that have an issue and let me put some code around it that would let make sure that once I am ready to re-pack the files, any damaged file is not included.